# NullPointerException while connecting through HTTPUrlConnection with JavaUpdate 51

Tags: java

My Java version is:

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

I have a server/device having untrusted certificate. When i connect to this device using `HttpURLConnection` its throwing `NullPointerException` as below.

The update51 has introduced many security things, but i belive it should pop-up a dialogue for the untrusted certificate not the `NullPointerException. Seems like a clear bug in Oracle java update51. I have created a bug in the [Java Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/) but i dont see my bug ID is visible in the bug database.

## Steps to reproduce.

```java
package com.xyz;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DMTrustManager.installDeployTrustManager();
        URL url = new URL("https://hostname/admin/version.xml");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br =
             new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String input;

        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
           System.out.println(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the URL with your server IP address which is having untrusted certificate.

I see the following exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.printWarningsIfRequired(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDeciderDialog.doShowDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDeciderDialog.showDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDeciderDialog.showDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.cisco.launcher.Test.main(Test.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Java couldn't trust Server
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.xyz.Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Java couldn't trust Server
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 12 more
```

Further note:

I see the `doShowDialog()` function in `com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDeciderDialog` has a new call to `printWarningsIfRequired` in `DeployManifestChecker` class.

```java
static void printWarningsIfRequired(URL paramURL, AppInfo paramAppInfo)
  {
    String str1 = (String)ToolkitStore.get().getAppContext().get("deploy-" + paramURL);
    Resource localResource = ResourceProvider.get().getCachedResource(paramURL, str1);
```

But here the `str1` itself null or the `Map` doesn't have any key called `"deploy-" + paramURL`. So I guess its failing there.

In my opinion the call to this function should be available only in case of a Web Start and not for the standalone applications.

Comment: In mentioned URL , web page not exist. Try will another URL.

Comment: I just mentioned some example there. please use some URL of your server which is running with untrusted certificate

Comment: @Rahul or the easiest way to reproduce is change your clock setting to Feb 2015 and try to access the "https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=gG7WUqLFIIrtoASevoGIBA" using the HTTPUrlConnection with java update 51. you will get the same exception i got.

Comment: Voting to close, as I don't actually see a question any where in there.  What's the expected behavior?